# Can photosyntetic cells be genetically modified to grow at a faster rate?

Tags: botany, cancer, photosynthesis

I hope the question is not silly, but I wonder if a sort of genetically modified plant "cancer" could be used for carbon sequestration. For example, cancer cells like [HeLa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HeLa) have been reproduced in tons, and as far as I know their growth rate is very high.

Comment: You might be interested in reading about [artificial photosynthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_photosynthesis).

Comment: Yes! Thanks, I was just reading that. I still think the question is relevant as we are relatively advanced in OGM, and tumors and plants already are there. It seems to me (I'm completely ignorant in biology) that it would be easier than reproduce cheap photosyntesis (i.e. cheaper than planting trees).